# Cardinality of product of ordinals without AC

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I want to prove, without the use of AC, that $|\alpha \cdot \beta|=|\alpha| \cdot |\beta|$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are ordinals. Any help?

Comment: In the absence of choice it's often clearer to talk about bijections instead of cardinalities. So you're asking for a bijection between $\alpha\cdot\beta$ and $\alpha\times\beta$, where "$\cdot$" refers to ordinal multiplication and "$\times$" refers to Cartesian product. This should help simplify things (HINT: how is $\alpha\cdot\beta$ defined?).

Comment: $\alpha \cdot \beta=\text{Ord}\big(\cup_{\gamma < \beta}\alpha_{\gamma} \times \lbrace \gamma \rbrace \big)$, with $\alpha_{\gamma}=\alpha$ for all $\gamma < \beta$. So one has a trivial between $\alpha \cdot \beta$ and $\alpha \times \beta$.

Comment: That's exactly right! (You should write that up as an answer to your own question and accept it. Or, I can if you prefer.)

Comment: But what in the case of addition? For the sum of two cardinals one must have a disjoint union.

Comment: Well, you didn't include addition in your question. Also, that statement is **false** in general (consider $\alpha=2,\beta=3$). So yes, the case of addition is more complicated.

Comment: Is there some sort of characterization for when $|\alpha + \beta|=|\alpha| + |\beta|$, besides the  fact that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have to be disjoint?

Comment: Two ordinals are **never** disjoint (unless one of them is zero) - by recursive definition, each ordinal literally is the set of all smaller ordinals. But yes, there is a simple characterization (try some examples out and see if you can see it).

Comment: @J.Bosser: In general two sets need not be disjoint. $|A|+|B|$ is defined as $|\{0\}\times A\cup\{1\}\times B|$, and the same works for ordinals, again with the obvious lexicographic ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two points here:

1. Every proof that refers *only* to well-ordered sets does not use the axiom of choice. The axiom of choice is used to *have* these well-orders in the first place, but when the sets given are well-ordered, the use of choice is redundant. (Do note that I mean *every* set in the proof, not that the theorem mentions well-ordered sets, but rather that the proof uses sets with well-orders on them.)
2. Depending on how you define ordinal arithmetic, or rather what you already know about this, your question is quite literally trivial. One of the definitions of $\alpha\cdot\beta$ is the lexicographic order on $\beta\times\alpha$, it is equivalent to the recursive definition as "iterated addition".

   Since the definition of $|\alpha|\cdot|\beta|$ is, literally, $|\alpha\times\beta|$, and it is easy to see that cardinal multiplication is commutative, the result follows.

But we also have an extra point.

3. Even if you work with the definitions based on recursion, it is not hard to prove that the cardinal arithmetic behaves as expected. Again, provided that you have proved certain properties of well-ordered sets. We do this by induction on $\beta$.

   For $\beta=0$ this is trivial, in fact for the finite case it is trivial. If $\beta$ is *not* a cardinal, then the result is also immediate by applying the induction hypothesis to some $\gamma<\beta$ such that $|\beta|=|\gamma|$.

   If $\beta$ is an infinite cardinal, that is $\beta\geq\omega$ and it is an initial ordinal, then one needs to check there is an obvious injection from $\sup\{\alpha\cdot\gamma\mid\gamma<\beta\}$ into $\alpha\times\beta$, and vice versa.